# How to dynamically add wmode=opaque to already displaying embed elements?

Tags: javascript, flash, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, embed

How to dynamically add `wmode="opaque"` to already displaying `embed` elements? Without reloading the elements, the embedded content should not lose its state.

Just setting the `wmode` attribute with javascript doesn't work.

Removing the element and then adding it again makes `wmode` take effect, but the flash element loses its state, among other problems. E.g if it's a video player its position/playback status resets. So that solution is no good.

Any other way of displaying content over the embedded element is acceptable as well.

(I'm doing this trough a content script in a Chrome extension if that is of any help.)

---

This is **not a duplicated** of [How to dynamically add wmode=transparent to Youtube embed code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818036/how-to-dynamically-add-wmode-transparent-to-youtube-embed-code) as there the parameter is added to a frame and not directly to the element it self.

Comment: I'm not sure that you can.  Is there a problem with doing this as soon as the page loads?  Or does that not help your extension?

Comment: @Brad, the extension is only invoked when user clicks a button (some time after a page has loaded), so I'd hope to avoid running content scripts and modifying pages where the user does not want to use the extension (most pages). (And in case dynamic `embed`s are created on the page at some time before the user invokes the extension, they would have to be tracked and altered, not sure if that's easy to do.)

Comment: @Qtax have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534474/changing-arbitrary-flash-objects-wmode-to-transparent

Comment: @GGG, doesn't `wrap()` remove and readd the element?

Comment: @Qtax no idea, I don't use jQuery. Does removing the element from the DOM and re-adding it reset the plugin?

Comment: @GGG, it does in my tests (as said in the question in the first place).

Comment: @Qtax I see it now. I seriously doubt this will work. The wmode attribute makes flash render in completely different ways... as a separate window or as part of the document, in the screen buffer or via the GPU, etc. Transitioning smoothly between those rendering modes would be quite a trick. Not saying Adobe couldn't have allowed for it, but I doubt this kind of thing is really a priority for them.

Comment: @Qtax is this for YouTube, though? There's any easy fix if so. Just asking because you linked another YouTube related post...

Comment: @GGG, not really, could be any site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`iframe` masks out the part of the flash it's over, allowing other elements to display over it. At least in Chrome.

This is what YouTube uses for their play list bar (at the bottom of the view port).

Comment: Could you expand your answer a little bit? Currently, there's no clear relationship between your question and answer (`<iframe>` pops up out of the blue).

Comment: @RobW, the goal was to display something over an embedded flash object (with the criteria in the question). Using an `<iframe>` like this is a workaround, and was the only solution I found.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but a bit tricky. If you don't mind using jQuery here is a nice way written by Jose Nobile http://www.nobilesoft.com/Scripts/fix_wmode2transparent_swf.js

If you want to stick to js then you can try something like shown here http://www.onlineaspect.com/2009/08/13/javascript_to_fix_wmode_parameters/

Hope it helps!

Comment: This re-adds the element, so that `embed`s state is lost. No good. :/

Comment: This causes the swf to refresh.